# Windows server2012r2 how to create multiple subdomain site

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I'm creating an application that accepting users as sub-domains,
Ex: {user_id}.mywebsite.com, thus, every request has to be *.mywebsite.com.

Problem is that every sub domain has to be bind on the iis
user1.mywebsite.com
user2.mywebsite.com  etc etc
My question is, is there a way to set a domain site to accept every sub-domain request?

This is basically what I want to do
[image: something like this?]

Is there any way to do it without adding every user as sub-domain to the iis site?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a catch-all site and then use ARR to forward the traffic,

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="site1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*).site1.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8091/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="site2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(.*).site2.com$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8092/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Other supporting steps can be found in [this blog post](https://blog.lextudio.com/wildcard-host-name-support-in-old-iis-releases-8e4448040b5a),

Comment: Thank you Lex, Actually by reading this blog I decided that an upgrade will be an easier (and better) solution since iis10 provides a wildcard host support so it allowed to create an all (*) subdomain host.